# Trying not to use eval() in php to evaluate a string with a condition statement

Tags: php, if-statement, eval, conditional-statements

I'm creating a validator that will be able to handle complex conditions by allowing the dev to use a conditional statement in the conditions rules.

Take this example with a set of rules:

```
...
"element_name":{
     "required": "conditional",
     "conditions" : {
         "requirements" : "(4 < 5)",
         "requirements" : "('something' == 'something_else')" 
     }
}
...
```

what the PHP will then do is loop through those `requirements` and evaluate them as code to return a boolean which will determine if the element is required or not.

The problem with using the `eval()` function is quite obvious. So I'm asking, given that condition statements are what will only be allowed, is there a safer way of doing this than:

```
$result = eval(element_name->requirements[0]);
```

Thank you guys.

---- UPDATE -----

Thank you Mike and everyone for the ideas, I wish I could mark you all as the answer because to be quite honest, I ended up using a little bit of everyone's idea. More of Mike's so he gets it.

So, this is probably something that is going to be looked at in the future because it's quite an attractive method of conditionally validating a field. My goal is to create an intuitive way of going about this. I liked the idea of simply slapping in a conditional statement right in the json config file. Of course, this would involve some serious security risks or a super complex parsing engine, so I ended requiring the dev to learn our method of conditional language, but as you will see, I kept it quite similar to the original one. I think it's important to have simple APIs otherwise you'll deter development on your platform. Check it out:

```
"element_name":{
     "required": "conditional",
     "conditions" : {
         "<" : ['4', '5'],
         "==" : [':element_id', ':other_element'], // will grab the values of those elements and compare
         "exp" : [['something', '==', 'something_else'], 'OR', [':other_element', '!=', '0']] 
     }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does the dev provide the list of requirements?

Comment: Mike I have to apologize, I've corrected my code. But once the dev has marked the `required` as `conditional` the dev is then expected to provide a `conditions` obj/array containing a list of conditions as seen above.

Comment: @FelipeTadeo http://www.php.net/manual/en/yaml.installation.php I am having a similar issue and would be using this if I could for conditionals, since it will run off the much faster libYAML C library. Unfortunately I need it to work on other people's systems without installing a module. Still, if you can use YAML - json is actually a subset and YAML has great logic enabling features.

Comment: @Philll_t it is a very old post, but maybe can you comment a bit more about your code to solve this kind of structure, are you using case statements for the operators? what are you using to replace the `:variables`? or resolving the `exp` operator? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @xavadu yeah I remember this a while back ago. This was pretty impressive and did the job right. I'll have to dig around for the code.

Comment: ey @Philll_t thanks for the reply, we already resolved it, we took some ideas from here, but finally we changed the latest format that you posted, because using the operator as a key have the limitation that can't be two equal operators (same key repeated)

Comment: I added explicit comparisons because of that. Considering the low amount of combinations required I didn’t feel like it was a big deal. Basically I had switch statement where I would run the key through. I should still post the code anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on dethtron5000's answer, one way I thought of doing this to prevent a ridiculously complex regex is to have the dev break up his conditionals into more of a multi-dimensional conditional thing and loop over it using a recursive function. At each level, you would have an "operator", which would be either "AND" or "OR" (at least I hope this is called an "operator", if not feel free to change it).

In your example you have: `(32 < 40 AND 10 > 5 OR 20 == 10)`

(It looks like you're json_encoding the conditionals, so I started with the following PHP array and worked backwards from there. I'm assuming you can just `json_decode` what your dev provides you to get a valid PHP array). The above example would be represented as the following PHP array:

```
$arr = array(
    'required' => 'conditional',
    'conditions' => array(
        'requirements' => array(
            'operator' => 'OR', // this makes it so that if any conditions at this level are true, it returns true
            0 => array(
                'operator' => 'AND', // this makes it so that all the conditions at this sub-level need to be satisfied to return true
                array(
                    'conditional1' => 32,
                    'conditional2' => 40,
                    'operation' => 'lessthan',
                ),
                array(
                    'conditional1' => 10,
                    'conditional2' => 5,
                    'operation' => 'greaterthan',
                ),
            ),
            1 => array(
                // Since there is only one condition here, it is not necessary to specify "AND" or "OR"
                array(
                    'conditional1' => 20,
                    'conditional2' => 10,
                    'operation' => 'equals',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

You can then loop through the conditionals with a recursive function like this:

```
function check_req(Array $reqs) {
    $operator = (isset($reqs['operator'])) ? $reqs['operator'] : 'AND';
    unset($reqs['operator']);
    foreach ($reqs as $req) {
        if (isset($req['operation'])) {
            switch ($req['operation']) {
                case 'lessthan':
                    $valids[] = $req['conditional1'] < $req['conditional2'];
                    break;
                case 'greaterthan':
                    $valids[] = $req['conditional1'] > $req['conditional2'];
                    break;
                case 'equals':
                    $valids[] = $req['conditional1'] == $req['conditional2'];
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            $valids[] = check_req($req);
        }
    }
    if ($operator == 'OR') {
        foreach ($valids as $valid) {
            if ($valid == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    else {
        foreach ($valids as $valid) {
            if ($valid == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

var_dump(check_req($arr['conditions']['requirements'])); // true in this case
```

When I json_encode it, I get:

```
{
    "required":"conditional",
    "conditions":{
        "requirements":{
            "operator":"OR",
            "0":{
                "operator":"AND",
                "0":{
                    "conditional1":32,
                    "conditional2":40,
                    "operation":"lessthan"
                },
                "1":{
                    "conditional1":10,
                    "conditional2":5,
                    "operation":"greaterthan"
                }
            },
            "1":[{
                "conditional1":20,
                "conditional2":10,
                "operation":"equals"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming this is what the dev would have to provide you.

Comment: Thank you Mike! Yes, it is called a logic operator, I get self-conscious when it comes to the jargon, so here's a quick list of definitions for future reference: Logic Operators = `AND OR` Comparison Operators `< > != == === ext..`. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: To keep it simple for the dev, I suppose we could take this idea and parse the string and create it into an array like the one you have provided, then have it execute as you placed here. It will be a hell of a job, but will definitely save time in the documentation and length of the json.

Comment: If your dev could provide you a json_encoded string like I have at the end here, you just [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) it in your code. No need for manually parsing it. It's already very close to how you have it now.

Comment: Also, this is a good way to check for errors. If json_decode can't decode (returns null), your dev did something wrong.

Comment: wouldn't any code wrapped in parentheses, if not a valid comparison statement, cause a parsing exception anyway?

Comment: I guess it's still not safe though because some php functions return boolean.

Comment: This is just an example. Of course, you would have to adapt it to how you want to do it, like throwing exceptions at certain places if the dev provdes "ADN" instead of "AND", etc so if an empty set of parentheses is provided, it will catch that. Also, to check for null, you can either use `isset()` or `=== null`. A boolean will return `true` for isset and `false` for === null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34204/discussion-between-felipe-tadeo-and-mike)

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to structure your JSON so that it limits the total set of operations that can be performed.  For example

```
"element_name":{
 "required": "conditional",
 "requirements" : [
        {
            "condition1": 4,
            "condition1": 5,
            "operation": "greaterthan"
        }
}
```

and then in your PHP (psedo-codey but you can get the idea):

```
foreach($requirements as $key => $test){
    switch($test->operation) {
        case 'greaterthan':
            return ($test->condition1 > $test->condition2);
        /// put other comparison types here

    }
}
```

This would mean coding more business logic but would ultimately be safer and would prevent injections like `eval`.

Comment: This is a great alternative. I was hoping to avoid doing something like this because then the dev is going to have dig through my documentation to figure out how to use this. Too bad it can't be as easy as my example above and safe. Maybe if i bust out a crazy regex, but I'm not very good at those.

Answer (score 2):

To decompose the initial text, could you use json_decode()?  This won't run anything, but will covert your big string into an array structure.

For the actual individual expressions, do you have access to [parsekit_compile_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parsekit-compile-string.php)?

This would allow the raw text to be converted into php bytecode ops.  It shouldn't be hard to interpret the ops via a switch statement.  Due to the constrained nature of what you said you expect in the requirements, this wouldn't be much code.

One could attempt regex without `parsekit_compile_string`, but this would be a more brittle solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use a switch statement vis:

switch($operator)

```
 case "==":
 return $a==$b;
 break;
 case "+":
 return $a+$b;
 break;

 etc...

 default:
 return false;
 break;
```

The key is how to send the parts to the switch - there are many ways after all.

It would be mad to expose eval() to untrusted user code.  I can see its use in situations like Drupal, where the uber-users can create PHP pages which are then evaluated as such, but of course only trusted users can do that.  Far better to restrict the code that can be run in this way.

EDIT:

In order to handle multiple operators, you still run this as your arithmetic unit, but you need to evaluate each operator separately.  This may mean you have to evaluate an instruction string one character at a time to pick up such as brackets.
It may be better to do the math in javascript on client side.  This is safe as long as the answer is not sent to your server (eval in JS can lead to DOM injection attacks)

If I might make an impertinent suggestion, do you REALLY need to do it this way?  Is there a better way, perhaps one that will deal with the input in smaller chunks?  If I were using this system, I'd probably pick up a desk calculator to do the work rather than use a website!  Try to do more of your users' work for them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! This is quite a doozy. I know the benefits of limiting the code, but consider the following condition if passed: `(32 < 40 AND 10 > 5 OR 20 == 10)`